# AutoHotKey doesn't recognise the Shuttle Xpress

Tags: autohotkey, keymapping

For some reason, I need the Shuttle Xpress keypad to map to keys like "Caps lock + v", "Ins + a". But the shuttle doesn't recognise the "Caps lock" as a modifier key. It can only map "Caps" or "Ins" alone. I try to use AutoHotKey software, but it failed to catch the shuttle's input signal. 
The shuttle has its own driver. How can I catch the Shuttle Xpress signal, and map it to any key combinations I want?
[image]

Comment: What does `KeyHistory` show?

Comment: @2501 The key history doesn't show anything! So i think AHK doesn't recognise the shuttle. The shuttle can only be mapped by its own driver.

Comment: Then Autohotkey itself cannot do much here.

Comment: @2501 yeah, it seems like this. But I also try to map the shuttle key, using its own driver, to some less frequently used combinations, like "Alt+j". And then use the AHK to map the "Alt+j" to "CapsLock + a". And it failed. Do you have any idea why is this? The shuttle indeed mapped to "Alt+j", and the "Alt+j" indeed mapped to "CapsLock+a", but the shuttle just would not be mapped to "CapsLock + a". How weird it is!

Comment: The shuttle is talking to the OS on a lower level. Autohotkey is made to intercept the keyboard and mouse and maybe a joystick.

Comment: Another way could be to to map the shuttle key, to open an AHK script (or a shortcut to this script) which does the same job as "CapsLock + a".

Answer (score 0):

You MIGHT be lucky and the device may be a "HID" device.
Most input devices (All keyboards, mice, "normal" joysticks, XBox controllers, PS4 controllers, etc, etc) are HID devices.

From a [cursory google](http://forums.contourdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=6553), it seems that it is a HID device or there is maybe some mode you can put the device in to make it a standard HID device?

In which case, AHK natively cannot read it, but it can be done through WinAPI calls (`DllCall()`) to the RawInput API.
There is a library called [AHKHID](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/38015-ahkhid-an-ahk-implementation-of-the-hid-functions/) that will let you read HID devices from AHK, and I am working on similar solutions (Though mine these days are tending to be written as a C# DLL which you then call from AHK), but I don't think I have anything that could help you at the moment - I have only implemented mouse movement in RawInput so far.
If / when I do though, I would post it on the AHK forums (I post as evilC), so keep an eye out there.

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround that enables me to map ShuttleXpress buttons to any keystroke sequence or scripts. The input is routed to ahk via the Fn keys. This works very well for my use, could be worth a try.

1: Remap Shuttle Xpress buttons to function keys between 13-24. (1-12 is of course also possible, but then you would tie up the physical Fn keys on the keyboard.)

2: Use ahk to remap the same function keys to any script or keystroke.